# Error :JsonStorage in Pig Local mode

Tags: json, format, apache-pig

I am running my Pigscript in Local mode in eclipse.
when I try to store the output in JsonStorage.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate:org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonStorage
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:473)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.QueryParser.NonEvalFuncSpec(QueryParser.java:4976)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.QueryParser.StoreClause(QueryParser.java:3473)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.QueryParser.BaseExpr(QueryParser.java:1351)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.QueryParser.Expr(QueryParser.java:893)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.QueryParser.Parse(QueryParser.java:706)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.LogicalPlanBuilder.parse(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1017)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:967)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:383)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:716)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:324)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerScript(PigServer.java:407)
    at com.paypal.debugpig.DebugPig.main(DebugPig.java:13)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:458)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:470)
    ... 14 more
```

PigScript :

```
REGISTER C:/path/to/jar/pig.jar;
REGISTER C:/path/to/jar/UpperUDf/UpperUDf_fat.jar;

A = LOAD 'C:/path/to/data/file/student.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS (name: chararray, age: int, gpa: float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.UPPER(name) ,age, gpa ;

Store B into 'output_student_Json' using org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonStorage();
```

when I dump or store the ouput in text file its working and but issues occurs when I try to store in JSON format.
Any pointers appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: no need to specify org.apache.pig.builtin.

Comment: @Fred :I get error the same if I just use JsonStorage();

Comment: which pig version are you using?

Comment: @Fred : I am adding pig.jar [(http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpigjar.htm)]in my in eclipse  external jar in udf and running the pig in local mode using Pigserver .

Comment: do you see JsonStorage in the jar? ;)

Comment: @Fred : It is working for me in pig grunt but the problem comes when I try to run it in eclipse .. Just realize no JsonStorage in that pig.jar ... so I tried with another [jar] (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html#udf-java) which I have built from now getting another error

Answer (score 0):

I have verified it, and it is working for me if i am using the below line of code for storing output into json file format.

```
store B into 'json_output' using JsonStorage();
```